# how create xml from sql data in one section

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have problem with create data in specify format. 
I need result like this:

```
<Units>
<Unit>0111024626914331</Unit>
<Unit>0111024626914348</Unit>
<Unit>00273129808000257576</Unit>
<Unit>00273129808000257590</Unit>
</Units>
```

my statement:

```
SELECT distinct PA.KOD_KRESKOWY as UNIT
        FROM LISTY_LINIOWE_POZ_P AS LLPP INNER JOIN PACZKI AS PA on PA.ID_PACZKI = LLPP.PACZKI_ID
        WHERE LISTY_LINIOWE_ID = 616665 
        FOR XML PATH ('UNITS'),type
```

give me result:

```
   <Units>
     <UNIT>P/000005/2018+1/3</UNIT>
   </UNITS>
   <UNITS>
     <UNIT>P/000005/2018+2/3</UNIT>
   </UNITS>
   <UNITS>
     <UNIT>P/000005/2018+3/3</UNIT
   </Units>
```

I have Units in one column in table.

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server I suppose? Try `FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE, ROOT ('Units')`.

Comment: thanks a lot it works.

Comment: @stickybit In this case I'd prefer to combine `AS [*]` with `PATH('UNIT')`...

Answer (score 3):

Although you've got you answer already it is worth to understand the levels of naming in `FOR XML PATH()`.

Btw: My solution for you would be slightly different:

```
 SELECT PA.KOD_KRESKOWY as [*]
 FROM LISTY_LINIOWE_POZ_P AS LLPP INNER JOIN PACZKI AS PA on PA.ID_PACZKI = LLPP.PACZKI_ID
 WHERE LISTY_LINIOWE_ID = 616665 
 GROUP BY PA.KOD_KRESKOWY
 FOR XML PATH ('UNIT'),ROOT('UNITS'),type;
```

- `GROUP BY` is better than `DISTINCT`
- `<UNIT>` is more kinda *row-tag*. With only one column it works with the empty `PATH('')` too.

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SomeValue VARCHAR(100), SomeNumber INT);
INSERT INTO @mockup 
VALUES('blah',1)
     ,('blub',2);
```

--Standard

```
SELECT SomeValue 
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('RowTag'),ROOT('RootTag')

<RootTag>
  <RowTag>
    <SomeValue>blah</SomeValue>
    <SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber>
  </RowTag>
  <RowTag>
    <SomeValue>blub</SomeValue>
    <SomeNumber>2</SomeNumber>
  </RowTag>
</RootTag>
```

--The first column will be a `text()` node below `<RowTag>`

```
SELECT SomeValue AS [*]
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('RowTag'),ROOT('RootTag')

<RootTag>
  <RowTag>blah<SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber></RowTag>
  <RowTag>blub<SomeNumber>2</SomeNumber></RowTag>
</RootTag>
```

--Both Columns have no name, funny effect...

```
SELECT SomeValue AS [*]
      ,SomeNumber AS [*]
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('RowTag'),ROOT('RootTag')

<RootTag>
  <RowTag>blah1</RowTag>
  <RowTag>blub2</RowTag>
</RootTag>
```

--Same Alias for both columns, might be also unexpected

```
SELECT SomeValue AS SameAlias
      ,SomeNumber AS SameAlias
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('RowTag'),ROOT('RootTag')

<RootTag>
  <RowTag>
    <SameAlias>blah1</SameAlias>
  </RowTag>
  <RowTag>
    <SameAlias>blub2</SameAlias>
  </RowTag>
</RootTag>
```

--empty `<RowTag>`

```
SELECT SomeValue 
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('RootTag')

<RootTag>
  <SomeValue>blah</SomeValue>
  <SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber>
  <SomeValue>blub</SomeValue>
  <SomeNumber>2</SomeNumber>
</RootTag>
```

--no `<RootTag>`

```
SELECT SomeValue 
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('RowTag')

<RowTag>
  <SomeValue>blah</SomeValue>
  <SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber>
</RowTag>
<RowTag>
  <SomeValue>blub</SomeValue>
  <SomeNumber>2</SomeNumber>
</RowTag>
```

--No `<RowTag>` and no `<RootTag>`

```
SELECT SomeValue 
      ,SomeNumber
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('')

<SomeValue>blah</SomeValue>
<SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber>
<SomeValue>blub</SomeValue>
<SomeNumber>2</SomeNumber>
```

--No tags at all

```
SELECT SomeValue AS [*]
      ,SomeNumber AS [*]
FROM @mockup 
FOR XML PATH('')

blah1blub2 <-- but this is still native XML-type!
```

This is important to know, because sometimes you can achieve the impossible :-D

If you want, you might test this with deeper paths too (`AS [Level1/Level2]`) and/or with attributes (`AS [Level1/Level2/@AnAttribute]`). Have fun!